# TFS permissions, default deny, specific allow

Tags: git, tfs, permissions

Recently we switched from source control from TFS to Git in TFS.
We want to protect our master branch from accidentally checks in.
So I want to deny all "regular" developers from contributing to this branch and a separate group of people who can contribute.
This can be done by tfs groups, but the problem is that deny wins over allows.
So I cant set default deny.
So when a new person arrives and I forget him to put in the "regular" developers group he will be able to checkin.
Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

"Not Set" permission means "implicitly deny" -- it will be denied by default, unless explicitly allowed.

Set your groups up *without* explicit deny permissions and then anyone can be a member of any set of groups, but only those who are members of groups with Allow permissions will be able to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you said "`deny wins over allows`". So, you can not add the same users to multiple groups. You need to add them to separated groups, that means one user only in one group.

For example `user1, user2` in **regular** group; `user3,user4` in a separate group, then `user3, user4` can contribute.

Another workaround is setting the `Branch Policies` for master branch to **force code review**. Thus the changes only can be checked in when the Admin or other specific user approved the changes.

[image]